# Use Native WiFi API to calculate received MAC Layer Frames?

Tags: winapi, sockets, wireless

I am trying using Windows Native WiFi API to get the number of packets and frames 
I received in a period of time.

For instance, if the packet size is set to less than MTU (ex. 1000bytes) , then the ideal number of received packet is equal to that of received frames.

I used the **WLAN_MAC_FRAME_STATISTICS** structure and its members **ullReceivedFrameCount** and **ullDecryptSuccessCount** to obtain the value, [see this website](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms706894%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

But the result is not what I thought, there are more frames I thought that may be the message between router and my computer in MAC layer, like beacon or something else.

My question is, is there any method to get MAC layer information rather than Native API or any method to deal with this problem to make the information more accurate?

Comment: Are you connected in 802.11n?

Comment: yeah, I connected internet via WiFi.

Comment: not in 802.11n , but does it matter??

Comment: yes, in N there are aggregations, so in upper layers you will see less packets

Answer (score 0):

I don't think such `API` exists. You're trying to get into the resolution of `MAC Layer` from the layers above. I believe allowing such things would violate the distinction of the layers. Each layer is a kind of black box to others with strictly defined set of exposed operations and data. If you want to count the actual data packets, you should look for an `API` in `IP or transport layer`, not in `MAC layer`.